# Sending multiple UITextField fields to a UITextView on a second ViewController (using a segue)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

Firstly, Im new to Objective-C and i'm currently following several tutorials. Apologies if this is an obvious solution. I did use the search for several hours and couldn't find a solution.

I have no problem understanding how to send a data from a single UITextField to a UITextView in a new view controller.

MY QUESTION IS: I want to populate the UITextView on the second view controller with all the users information they entered into the UITextField when they press the button.

[IMAGE OF LAYOUT](http://hostmypicture.com/images/1qzq.jpg)

The code I used to populate the UITextView with 'Name' is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) //will return true so will start segue 
    {
        ViewControllerTwo *ViewControllerTwo = [segue destinationViewController];

        ViewControllerTwo.Name = sendName.text;
    }
}
```

I'm sure to send the rest of the form over is simple but right now I just can't think of a solution.

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with Xcode.  2. Please understand the difference between a textview, textfield, and NSString values.

Comment: 3. The segue will perform regardless of whether or not your `if` statement returns `YES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create more properties for the information in ViewControllerTwo.h. For example if you wanted to add the users age.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) int age;
```

Set the value of the age in your prepareForSegue Method from the text the user enters into the field.

```
ViewControllerTwo.age = [ageTextField.text intValue];
```

In ViewControllerTwo.m build a string with all these properties and set the UITextView text equal to entire string.

```
NSString *userInformation = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %d", name, age];
```

Set your UITextView.text property equal to userInformation

Comment: `ViewControllerTwo.age = [ageTextField.text intValue];`  Though... as long as we only need to pass the information from one text field to another, I hardly see much point in converting it from a string to an int just to convert it back to a string again.  I'd just make `age` an `NSString` property myself.

Comment: It would actually be easier if you made an NSString from all the info before passing the information to ViewControllerTwo. Then pass that NSString into a NSString property. No need to make several properties when only one could be used.